# Syncing Django Models with Overriden Save Method

Tags: python, django

I have a `client` and a `user` model. Both `client` and `user` have a flag called `help_desk`. The help desk clients and users are to be kept in sync. This means that:

- When user is marked as `help_desk` they are added to all help desk clients
- When user is unmarked as `help_desk` they are removed from all help desk clients
- When a client is marked as `help_desk` all help desk users added to it
- When a client is unmarked as `help_desk` all help desk users are removed from it

I've been trying to solve this by overriding the `save()` method with the following:

##### Client

```py
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    help_desk_users = get_user_model().objects.filter(is_help_desk=True)
    if self.help_desk:
        for user in help_desk_users:
            self.users.add(user)
    else:
        for user in self.users.all():
            if user in help_desk_users:
                self.users.remove(user)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

##### User

```py
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.is_help_desk:
        for client in Client.objects.filter(help_desk=True):
            client.users.add(self)
    else:
        for client in Client.objects.filter(help_desk=True):
            client.users.remove(self)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The user code is working as expected but the client code is not. I think the reason is because you are unable to bulk update in an overriden save method - see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods). My question is, is this simply a limitation of Django? And if so, what are the best practice alternative solutions for solving a problem like this?

Comment: Why do you need a separate Client.users m2m? Isn't it enough to just query users with the helpdesk flag set?

Comment: @AKX The front-end already uses the `users` field and I wouldn't want to have to add additional logic everywhere just for the help desk users (ex `if (client.users || helpDeskUsers)`. Do you think something like a computed field could work here?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else looking for a solution, the code above actually works just not when  saving through the admin panel. If you want the functionality to work while saving from the admin panel, you have to override the `save_related` function. Here's an [article](https://timonweb.com/django/many-to-many-field-save-method-and-the-django-admin-caveat/) explaining the problem more.